Channing problem when modeling timefold/optaplanner for vehicle routing and task assigning in one solution?
I am currently engaged in the development of an application where task allocation to resources over a defined period is crucial. The objective is to optimize travel time between tasks while ensuring they are executed in order of priority. To accomplish this, I am utilizing OptaPlanner (OP) and adhering to specific constraints and task dependencies.
I have structured my planning entities and solution using @PlanningListVariable, Inverse relation shadow variable, and Previous and next element shadow variable, as illustrated below:
@PlanningEntity
public class Resource {
  @PlanningId
  private Long id;
...
  @PlanningListVariable
  private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
...
}

@PlanningEntity
public class Task {
  @PlanningId
  private UUID id;
...
  @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tasks")
  private Resource resource;
  @PreviousElementShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tasks")
  protected Task previousTask;
  @NextElementShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tasks")
  protected Task nextTask;
...
}

@PlanningSolution
public class OPPlanningSolution {
  private Long id;

  @ConstraintConfigurationProvider
  private OPConstraintConfiguration opConstraintConfiguration;

  @ValueRangeProvider
  @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
  private List<OPTask> tasks;
  @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
  private List<OPResource> resources;
  @PlanningScore
  private HardMediumSoftScore score;
...
}

Initially, this approach sufficed. However, I encountered a challenge when attempting to incorporate task dependencies into the problem. For instance, Task T2 must commence only after Task T1 concludes, Tasks T3 and T4 must start simultaneously. I envision the scheduling to resemble the following pattern across resources R1 and R2:
R1: |--T1--|*******|--T4--|
R2: *******|--T2--||--T3--|

While Task T1 is straightforward, Task T2 depends on Task T1, and Tasks T3 and T4 are dependent on each other.
In task class I have information on which tasks current task depends on and what type of dependency it is.
My dilemma arises in effectively incorporating these dependencies into the scheduling process within OptaPlanner. While exploring potential solutions, I referred to paragraph 20 of the OptaPlanner documentation and watched a relevant video, yet I haven't been able to devise a satisfactory solution.
One approach I experimented with was reversing the logic: assigning resources to tasks. Although this allowed me to instruct OptaPlanner to allocate time to tasks, I faced challenges in retaining information about the previous and next tasks, crucial for calculating travel time between tasks and minimizing it if necessary.
Although I'm on the verge of a solution with this approach, I sense it may not be the most efficient. Hence, I seek guidance and insights on alternative strategies or refinements to address this issue effectively.
Thank you for your attention and assistance.

If I get your case right, my approach regarding this case would be:

store the list of mandatory previous tasks of a task in the task ("Hashmap<int,task> mandatorytasks" where key of the map is the id of the task )
Create a hard constraint for every taks that goes previous to previous and check that all mandatory tasks are in the previouses

Hope this helps
